# time and date functions gives wrong output in php

Tags: php, date, time

What I'm trying to do is to return the rest of this simple equation as date.

```
$time = (time()+(60*60*12)) - time();
$date = date('d H:i:s', $time);
echo $date;
```

As you see i have added 12 hours, but this added 1 day + 2 hours. And i stuck here :/.

Output is `01 14:00:00`

Expected is `00 12:00:00`

So what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have tried `date_default_timezone_set()` function but it seems to not work for me :/

**NEW EDIT**

I realize when i do this.

```
$time = time() - time();
$date = date('d H:i:s', $time);
echo $date;
```

Print out `01 02:00:00` what is that?

Comment: What is you trying to achieve here? It's won't work cause date function gives given format date-time of given timestamp which is currently (60*60*12).

Comment: I'm sorry if i didn't explain good, i want to minus old time from new time. old time could be 100 second > new time or could be 3 days > new time.

Comment: @IrisTako have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using  `DateTime`-

```
$start = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime();
$end->modify('+12 hour');
$interval = $end->diff($start);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');

echo $elapsed;
```

Comment: WOW this works like a charm, Thaaanks for saving my time.

Answer (score -1):

Not the answer to your question, but take a look at [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/), "A simple PHP API extension for DateTime.". Very useful for these kind of DateTime-problems.